# How to display content from AFC repeater field?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have just begun using the ACF repeater field type to display a grid of projects on my site. The repeater field is named "projects" and I am using get sub field to display the content. However no content is displaying and the image is only displayed as the image path. I already have the styling for the fields i just need them to display.

```
<?php if (have_rows('projects')): ?>
                                <div class="section group project-grid"><!-- start of grid row-->
                                    <div class="col span_1_of_4">
                                     <img class="inner-line-break" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/bio.png"  />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col span_1_of_4 project-data-title">
                                        <p class="project-name"><?php the_sub_field ('name'); ?></p>
                                        <p>Programme:<br /><?php the_sub_field ('programme'); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col span_1_of_4 project-data">
                                        <p>Website:<br /><a href="http://www.eurobioimaging.eu"><?php the_sub_field ('website'); ?></a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col span_1_of_4 project-data">
                                        <p>Services:<br />  <p><?php the_sub_field ('services_icons'); ?></p>

                                        <p><a href="#" data-tooltip="Proposal Writing"><i class="fa fw fa-clone hover-icon"></i></a> <a href="#" data-tooltip="Contract Negotiations"><i class="fa fw fa-file-text-o hover-icon"></i></a> <a href="#" data-tooltip="Project Management"> <i class="fa fw fa-calendar-check-o hover-icon"></i></a></p> </p>
                             </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div> <!--end of grid row-->

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: also, they have very good resources on their website, please read them first. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Answer (score 1):

You're only testing if there are rows but you're not actually iterating over them and populating the variables (using the_row()). Try it like this:

```
while ( have_rows('projects') ) : the_row();
  the_sub_field('sub_field_name');
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code:

```
<?php if(have_rows('projects')) : while (have_rows('projects')) : the_row();
    $name = get_sub_field('name');
    $programme = get_sub_field('programme');
    $website = get_sub_field('website');
    $services = get_sub_field('services_icons');
    ?>


                                    <div class="section group project-grid"><!-- start of grid row-->
                                        <div class="col span_1_of_4">
                                         <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logo['alt'] ?>" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col span_1_of_4 project-data-title">
                                            <p class="project-name"><?php echo $name; ?></p>
                                            <p>Programme:<br /><?php echo $programme; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col span_1_of_4 project-data">
                                            <p>Website:<br /><a href="http://www.eurobioimaging.eu"><?php echo $website; ?></a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col span_1_of_4 project-data">
                                            <p>Services:<br />  <p><?php echo $$services; ?></p>

                                            <p><a href="#" data-tooltip="Proposal Writing"><i class="fa fw fa-clone hover-icon"></i></a> <a href="#" data-tooltip="Contract Negotiations"><i class="fa fw fa-file-text-o hover-icon"></i></a> <a href="#" data-tooltip="Project Management"> <i class="fa fw fa-calendar-check-o hover-icon"></i></a></p> </p>
                                 </div>

                                        </div><?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                                    </div> <!--end of grid row-->
```